# I need to check nodejs is installed or not in my ststem using batch script

Tags: batch-file

```
@echo off
cls 
echo %errorlevel%     
set nodeV=    
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('node -v') do @set nodeV=%%a
if  %nodeV% NEQ [] ( 
  ECHO node version -%nodeV%
) else (
   ECHO some internal error occured
)
echo %errorlevel%
```

When node js is installed that rime it is working correctly.
When not installed it showing error node is not internal and external command
How can we check this software installed or not

Thank You

Comment: Check for node version node --version  from your command prompt.

Comment: give command <node --version >

Comment: actually am interested to do silent installation of node js so i need to check if it is already installed or not.

Comment: can you help me?

Comment: change your if condition to `if  "%nodeV%" NEQ ""` ...

Comment: 'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command, it is the error when not installed

Comment: to make error not visible -> `for /f "delims=" %%a in ('node -v 2^>nul')`

Comment: "%nodeV%" NEQ "" it showing "" not expected

Comment: thank You all.  I got result now

Comment: set nodeV=  
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('node -v 2^>nul') do @set nodeV=%%a
if exist %nodeV%  ( ECHO node version - %nodeV%) else ( ECHO not installed)

Comment: `where node || echo not installed`

Comment: @SouravGhadai : I'm trying to do the same and I used your solution     
     set nodeV= for /f "delims=" %%a in ('node -v 2^>nul') do set nodeV=%%a if exist %nodeV% ( ECHO node version - %nodeV%) else ( ECHO not installed). However, even when I have node installed it always go to the else block. Did this work for you?

Comment: `if exist` checks for file existence and `%nodeV%` is just a string with a ver number. one should use `if DEFINED nodeV` to check if the variable was defined.